# Lower case urls and trailing slash

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC 6 and am trying to use lower case url's and trailing slash.

I have used the following:

```
RouteTable.Routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
RouteTable.Routes.AppendTrailingSlash = true;
```

But it gives a compile error. Just wanted to know if MVC 6 has a different way to do the above or is the same as we did in MVC5?

Comment: http://gurustop.net/blog/2012/09/01/asp-net-mvc-seo-lowercase-url-iis-rewrite-net45-nuget/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those APIs have not yet been ported from ASP.NET 4.x (used by MVC 5.x and earlier) to ASP.NET 5, which is used by MVC 6.

The feature request to support lowercase URLs is logged here (and isn't yet resolved): https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/issues/140 (please note that it's in the Routing repo because this is a Routing feature and not specific to MVC).

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is open-source now.  How tough could it be to port?

Comment: @RobertHarvey MVC has indeed been open source for several years. In this case it's not a question of difficulty, but rather scheduling and priority. I did just add a "+1" to the issue request on GitHub after I answered this question, so that is effectively a bump up in priority.

Comment: Oh, wait.  I answered my own question; MVC4 wasn't open-source, was it?

Comment: Mvc4 was opened source as well :)

Comment: And here is a workaround sample https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/test/WebSites/UrlHelperWebSite/CustomUrlHelper.cs

Comment: @RobertHarvey in this particular case, it was Routing that was not open source (because it was part of .NET Framework) until ASP.NET 5.

Answer (score 22):

You can now use AddRouting to tell the routing engine to use lowercase URL's. This code goes in the Startup.cs file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...ommitted code

    services.AddRouting(options =>
    {
        options.AppendTrailingSlash = true;
        options.LowercaseUrls = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: That's great! A semicolon is missed after the first true

Comment: From the .NET Core 1.0.1 the correct syntax is `services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>` instead of `services.ConfigureRouting(options =>`

Comment: Updated to use `AddRouting`

Comment: How can I add trailing slashes in asp.net core 2.0 web api? I tried this, but its not working.

Comment: @zuckerthoben `options.AppendTrailingSlash = true;`

Answer (score 7):

From the .NET Core 1.0.1 the correct syntax to implement the trailing slash and lowercase urls is:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Omitted code
    // ...

    // Configure routing.
    services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.AppendTrailingSlash = true;
        options.LowercaseUrls = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: Has this changed in asp.net core 2.0 ?

Comment: @user4344677 It looks like it is still done this way in asp.net core 2.1